# Saving really big uiimage files

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I made an app that creates really big images made out of text (the largest one is about ten times the size of the iphone screen). I tried using the`UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`, but that saved it in much lower resolution. Is there anyway to save the image with full quality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `NSFileManager`. Create a sub directory in your app sandBox where you will save your file (image). This of course is relevant if you do not want the image to be saved in the iOS photo album and have it private for your app.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIImage *)renderLayerOf:(UIView *)yourView {
     //in this case 'yourView' is the label containing the large text
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(yourView.frame.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [[yourView layer] renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

This method will convert any UIView to an Image. after you get the Image u can save is using NSFileManager. I hope this helps you out.